# What table size is small enough for MAPJOIN?

Tags: hive

How do I decide whether a table is small enough for the `MAPJOIN` optimization?

My guess is that I should look at

```
du /misc/hdfs/user/hive/warehouse/my_table
```

and use `MAPJOIN` if that is below 50% (? 5%?) of RAM.

I am using hive 0.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hive-site.xml](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)

> `hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize`
>   Default Value: **25000000**
>   The threshold for the input file size of the small tables; if the file size is smaller than this threshold, it will try to convert the common join into map join.

This is the current release Wiki, but I think this setting goes back to 0.10.

Comment: thanks for the info(and +1), but this is not quite what I was asking about; I am wondering how I should adjust this threshold depending on my file size.

Comment: This value is the file size. Is difficult to estimate how much of the *task RAM* can be used for this, it depends on what other operators you have in the map task, how many 'small tables' are joined etc. All *columns used* from all small tables must be loaded in RAM. The other big memory consumers are the map join hash table and aggregates hash tables. The good news is that both can actually 'flush' under memory pressure (at the cost of the shuffle doing more work). I suggest try out. For sure your `hive.mapjoin.localtask.max.memory.usage` must fit the small table, but that is local.